# Laravel Nova not working/showing up on nova route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I bought nova and installed it like its written in the docs. After the Installation, I run the composer sucsessfully and install it by nova:install. I see the nova-api Routes in the Route:list but can't access Nova Panel via Browser. I only get the package content. What do I do wrong?

Screenshot Browser
[image]

Screenshot 2
[image]

Comment: Looks like your webserver is not configured properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to write your .env APP_URL:APP_PORT/nova

Like this

```
http://localhost:8000/nova or http:192.168.1.1:8000/nova
```